# Does TerminateThread() release a mutex？

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mutex

I want to use `TerminateThread()` to terminate a thread.  If, at that time, a mutex is held by the thread, will the mutex be released after `TerminateThread()`?

Comment: No. In C++ return from your thread function to complete it. Do not call ExitThread or all kind of stuff will leak.

Comment: yes, mutex is released - [*If a thread terminates without releasing its ownership of a mutex object, the mutex object is considered to be abandoned. A waiting thread can acquire ownership of an abandoned mutex object, but the wait function will return WAIT_ABANDONED to indicate that the mutex object is abandoned.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects)

Comment: You can't call `ExitThread()` on another thread, it terminates only the calling thread. So, if a thread is terminating itself, and if it has a mutex locked, why wouldn't it want to release the mutex correctly before terminating? This sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: I describe my question env more detailed. I create the thread in a dll (windows LSP), in the LSP dll I will invoke a function which implemeted in the dll. and the LSP may be dettached by user App, so I will terminate the thread when recieve DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. If I exit the thread by my code, it has opportunity to invoke the function, but at that time, the dll has been detached, it seems that function address already not exist in process address space, and it will cause coredump.(eg. if set flag to break out the thread mainloop, it may in sleep, after sleep before exit it will call the func)

Comment: By the way, I don't find how to let thread interrupt from sleep or wait using windows API or C++11 Thread. Just like java thread.interrupt() or boost::thread::interrupt()?

Comment: Yes, I want to terminate the thread in other thread, and want to use TerminateThread() function, not TerminateThread(). this is a describe mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to Win32 mutexes, any thread attempting to acquire the mutex locked by an another thread that exited will get WAIT_ABANDONED after calling  WaitForSingleObject. Treat this is as a success case.

So have your Win32 mutex acquiring code be like this:

```
DWORD dwResult = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, dwTimeout);
bool gotMutex = ((dwResult == 0) || (dwResult == WAIT_ABANDONED));
```

I don't know what it means for Win32 Critical Sections and std::mutex, but I would guess those data structures would stay locked.

Comment: "*Treat this is as a success case*" - only the wait itself will be a success, but the data being protected by the mutex will be in an unknown state, so don't trust it. See [Understanding the consequences of WAIT_ABANDONED](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050912-14/?p=34253).

Comment: That's a fair point. OP needs to consider why he thinks ExitThread without releasing the mutex is a good idea.